Create Oscript file without adding line break
I have Oscript Code that takes the md5 hesh line and creates a txt file with the value inside, but in the end file, I got a line break symbol, which is unacceptable for API that checks that md5 hash. I checked the retVal.md5Hex and it doesn't contain any line breaks, so there is a problem with File.Write I guess. I don't have access to Oscript documentation, so there might be a really easy solution.
retVal.ok = True 
File indexTXT = File.StringToFile(filePath+"/index-md5.txt")
File.Create(indexTXT)
File f1 = File.Open(filePath+"/index-md5.txt", File.WriteMode) 
if (!IsError( f1 ) )
    retVal = ARASS::utils::ExtractionUtils.GenerateMD5Hash(filePath+"/index.xml") 
    File.Write(f1, retVal.md5Hex)
    File.Close(f1)

I need a native Oscript solution in the code snippet I sent. Thanks.
